# Non blocking locking

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to start some new threads each for one repeating operation. But when such an operation is already in progress, I want to discard the current task. In my scenario I need very current data only - dropped data is not an issue.

In the MSDN I found the `Mutex` class but as I understand it, it waits for its turn, blocking the current thread. Also I want to ask you: **Does something exist in the .NET framework already, that does the following**:

1. Is some method M already being executed?
2. If so, `return` (and let me increase some counter for statistics)
3. If not, start method M in a new thread

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `lock(someObject)` statement, which you may have come across, is syntactic sugar around `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`.

However, if you use the monitor in this more verbose way, you can also use `Monitor.TryEnter` which allows you to check if you'll be able to get the lock - hence checking if someone else already has it and is executing code.

So instead of this:

```
var lockObject = new object(); 

lock(lockObject)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

try this **(option 1)**:

```
int _alreadyBeingExecutedCounter;
var lockObject = new object();

if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
{
   // you'll only end up here if you got the lock when you tried to get it - otherwise you'll never execute this code.

    // do some stuff

    //call exit to release the lock
    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
else
{
    // didn't get the lock - someone else was executing the code above - so I don't need to do any work!
   Interlocked.Increment(ref _alreadyBeingExecutedCounter);
}
```

(you'll probably want to put a try..finally in there to ensure the lock is released)

or dispense with the explicit lock althogether and do this

**(option 2)**

```
private int _inUseCount;

public void MyMethod()
{
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _inUseCount) == 1)
    {
        // do dome stuff    
    }
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _inUseCount);
}
```

**[Edit: in response to your question about `this`]**

No - don't use `this` to `lock` on. Create a privately scoped object to act as your lock.

Otherwise you have this potential problem:

```
public class MyClassWithLockInside
{
    public void MethodThatTakesLock()
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            // do some work
        }
    }
 }

public class Consumer
{
    private static MyClassWithLockInside _instance = new MyClassWithLockInside();

    public void ThreadACallsThis()
    {
          lock(_instance)
          {
              // Having taken a lock on our instance of MyClassWithLockInside,
              // do something long running
              Thread.Sleep(6000);
           }
    }

    public void ThreadBCallsThis()
    {
         // If thread B calls this while thread A is still inside the lock above,
         // this method will block as it tries to get a lock on the same object
         // ["this" inside the class = _instance outside]
         _instance.MethodThatTakesLock();
    }  
}
```

In the above example, some external code has managed to disrupt the internal locking of our class just by taking out a lock on something that was externally accessible.

Much better to create a private object that you control, and that no-one outside your class has access to, to avoid these sort of problems; this includes not using `this` or the type itself `typeof(MyClassWithLockInside)` for locking.

Comment: Would `this` be a suitable lockObject?

Comment: shouldn't Monitor.Exit be in a finally block of a try section ?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to work with a reentrancy sentinel:

You could define an `int` field (initialize with 0) and update it via [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) on entering the method and only proceed if it is 1. At the end just do a [`Interlocked.Decrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y.aspx).

Another option:

From your description it seems that you have a Producer-Consumer-Scenario...

For this case it might be helpful to use something like [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) as it is thread-safe and mostly lock-free...

Another option would be to use [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) or [`ConcurrentStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx)...

Comment: @DerMike I would give you an example but I would need more information... basically these collections have `Try` methods which don't block... please check also my update above regarding `Interlocked` usage...

Answer (score 1):

You might find some useful information on the following [site](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Aborting_Threads)  (the PDf is also downlaodable - recently downloaded it myself).  The Adavnced threading Suspend and Resume or Aborting chapters maybe what you are inetrested in.

Comment: I would read the whole article, i have found it indispensable, http://www.albahari.com/threading/ from the begining

Answer (score 0):

You should use Interlocked class atomic operations - for best performance - since you won't actually use system-level sychronizations(any "standard" primitive needs it, and involve system call overhead).
//simple non-reentrant mutex without ownership, easy to remake to support //these features(just set owner after acquiring lock(compare Thread reference with Thread.CurrentThread for example), and check for matching identity, add counter for reentrancy)
//can't use bool because it's not supported by CompareExchange
private int lock;

```
public bool TryLock()
{
  //if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _inUseCount) == 1)      
  //that kind of code is buggy - since counter can change between increment return and
  //condition check - increment is atomic, this if - isn't.       
  //Use CompareExchange instead
  //checks if 0 then changes to 1 atomically, returns original value
  //return true if thread succesfully occupied lock
  return CompareExchange(ref lock, 1, 0)==0;
  return false;

}
public bool Release()
{
  //returns true if lock was occupied; false if it was free already
  return CompareExchange(ref lock, 0, 1)==1;
}
```