# Wait for a lock to be released

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a thread.  At a certain point, what I want to do is check if a certain lock is free.  If it is free, I want the thread to continue on its merry way.  If it is not free, I want to wait until it is free, but then not actually acquire the lock.

Here is my code so far:

```
private object LockObject = new Object();

async void SlowMethod() {
  lock (LockObject) {
    // lotsa stuff
  }
}

void AppStartup() {
  this.SlowMethod();
  UIThreadStartupStuff();
  // now, I want to wait on the lock.  I don't know where/how the results
  // of SlowMethod might be needed.  But I do know that they will be needed.
  // And I don't want to check the lock every time.
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033725/c-sharp-how-to-detect-an-object-is-already-locked

Comment: @dizel3d That's a different operation.  Determining if the lock is free is different from waiting until its free without acquiring the lock.

Comment: If your example code is representative of your real problem, then you could just `Wait` on the task returned by `SlowMethod`.

Comment: Pretty unlikely you are using that *lock* statement appropriately.  Use AutoResetEvent for signaling.  Use Task as a return value for async code so you can wait it.

Comment: Do you want to start only after `SlowMethod` completes? Or should they execute in parallel?

Comment: They should execute in parallel.  The point is I'm trying to speed up my startup.

Comment: Any reason you're not offloading `SlowMethod` to a background thread?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have classical XY problem. I guess what you want is start a Task with you `SlowMethod` and then Continue it with the `UIThreadStartupStuff` is UI thread.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>SlowMethod())
     .ContinueWith(t=>UIThreadStartupStuff(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

or with async/await (make your `SlowMethod` to return Task)

```
try
{
   await SlowMethod();
}
catch(...)
{}
UIThreadStartupStuff();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use a lock here. You need an event. Either [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) or [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Remember, locks are used for mutual exclusion. Events are used for signaling.

You have your `SlowMethod` set the event when it's done. For example:

```
private ManualResetEvent DoneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

async void SlowMethod() {
  // lotsa stuff
  // done with lotsa stuff. Signal the event.
  DoneEvent.Set();
}

void AppStartup() {
  this.SlowMethod();
  UIThreadStartupStuff();

  // Wait for the SlowMethod to set the event:
  DoneEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I might not get what you want to achieve, but why not wait on the lock "properly"?
After all, it is a clear sign of the lock being free if you can take it.
Also, you can release it immediately if it is important.

```
void AppStartup() {
    this.SlowMethod();
    UIThreadStartupStuff();

    // now, I want to wait on the lock.  I don't know where/how the results
    // of SlowMethod might be needed.  But I do know that they will be needed.
    // And I don't want to check the lock every time.

    lock (LockObject) {
        // nothing, you now know the lock was free
    }

    // continue...
```

}