# Non-blocking locking- Validation of concept and follow-up

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This is more a validation of concept question. I hope I am not transgressing on the acceptable questions rule here on SO. I tried commenting on the answer thread, but SO does not allow me to do so.

Leading off from the accepted answer for this question, which is a question I had as well - [Non blocking locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209590/non-blocking-locking),

Option 2 for the accepted answer is this:

```
private int _inUseCount;

public void MyMethod()
{
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _inUseCount) == 1)
    {
        // do some stuff    
    }
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _inUseCount);
}
```

it seems like the thread that does the increment may not necessarily be the thread that executes the "//do some stuff" part of the code. 
 
 
Consider this scenario:

- ThreadA increments _inUseCount to 1 and suspends
- ThreadB increments _inUseCount to 2 and suspends
- ThreadA resumes and sees that _inUseCount is equal to 2, does not execute the "do some stuff" part of the code, decrements _inUseCount to 1 and finishes
- ThreadB resumes and sees that _inUseCount is 1 and executes the "do some stuff" part of the code

And is there some way using this paradigm to ensure that the thread that does the increment is the thread that executes the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the thread that does the increment may not necessarily be the thread that executes the "//do some stuff"

That is wrong. They're part of one code-path and will execute on the same thread.

But only when a Thread finds `_inUseCount==0` when it starts will it execute "some stuff" . Otherwise it will skip that part.

---

> Consider this scenario:
>
> - ThreadA increments _inUseCount to 1 and suspends
> - ThreadA resumes and sees that _inUseCount is equal to 2, does not execute the "do some stuff" part of the code, decrements _inUseCount
>     to 1 and finishes

ThreadA executes `if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _inUseCount) == 1)` and it is the contract of `Interlocked.Increment()` that this Thread will see as the return value what its own Increment did.

So while it is possible that *"ThreadA resumes and sees that inUseCount is equal to 2"*, this is not what the code does. It looks at the return value of `Increment()` and that does not depend on any suspend/resume scenario.

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman. Thanks for your answer. Consider this scenario- ThreadA increments _inUseCount to 1 and suspends, ThreadB increments _inUseCount to 2 and suspends. ThreadA resumes and sees that _inUseCount is equal to 2, does not execute the "do some stuff" part of the code, decrements _inUseCount to 1 and finishes. ThreadB resumes and sees that _inUseCount is 1 and executes the "do some stuff" part of the code.

Comment: Add this to the question. But `Interlocked` makes your scenario impossible.

Comment: As far as I understand, Interlocked.Increment will perform increment of the variable and storing it back in one atomic operation. Is there something I am missing about how Interlocked works which makes you say that my scenario will be impossible?

Comment: @HenkHolterman- Thanks for your updated answer. If that is how Interlocked.Increment works, then it sure would make my scenario impossible. I am guessing there's some caching that happens once the value is incremented and stored. So I could say, it is this increment and caching that is an atomic operation.